# How to express that a feature requires a certain JRE

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, tycho, p2

I use Tycho (currently v0.24) to build a p2 repository, containing a feature which in turn contains a plug-in.

The manifest of the plug-in states that it requres Java 1.8

```
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.8
```

If I use the *Install New Software* wizard of the Eclipse IDE to install this feature, it allows to install it even though the JRE that Eclipse is running on does not meet the required execution environment.

After restarting Eclipse, the just installed plug-ins are simply not picked up - quite rightfully so because of the unresolved requirement. But unaware users will wonder why the hell the installed feature doesn't show up.

Therefore I think there should be at least a warning in this case. I've opened also [this bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=483383) but didn't get a respoonse so far.

In the meanwhile, is it possible to do *something* so that an attempt to install the feature on an unsupported JRE will fail?

Comment: I can recommend an untried workaround, include a plug-in in your feature with a low BREE and have it do a check for JRE version or installed state of plug-ins and provide proactive (but a little late) advice to the user.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this clever trick. However, the checking plug-in would need an early startup to be useful which contradicts the whole lazy concept of Eclipse plug-ins, adds to startup time, etc. Plus, I would really like to be able to catch this case earlier.